# What's wrong in this code ? It is not working! Everytime else condition is working

Tags: python

```
def keti():
    if payf=="y":
        print("The fees are {}".format(amount))
        if payf == "n":
            amount = amount +10
            print ("the fees are {}".format (amount ))

def keti2():
    if payf=="y":
        amount =2*amount
        print("The fees are {}".format(amount))
        if payf == "n":
            amount =2*amount
            amount = amount +10
            print ("the fees are {}".format (amount ))

ket=int(input("no of kts"))
print(ket)
payf = str(input("hav u paid"))
print (payf)
amount=250
if (ket=="1"):
    keti()
elif (ket=="2"):
    keti2 ()
else:
    print ("wrong input")
```

What's wrong in this?
Every time else statement is executed
I don't get what is going wrong in this

What's wrong in this?
Every time else statement is executed
I don't get what is going wrong in this

Comment: You're comparing an int to a string. `1 == "1"` will always be False.

Comment: beside the problem of comparing strings to ints ... how do you think after a valid `payf=="y":` can there ever be a truthy `if payf == "n":` in its block, unless you modify `payf` in between. Or is this just a case of bad indentation?

Comment: try learning debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
ket=int(input("no of kts"))     # you have converted ket into int object 
print(ket)
if (ket=="1"):                   # here your trying to compare an int object and string object ,try it with ket==1 or ket==int("1")
    keti()
elif (ket=="2"):
    keti2 ()
else:
    print ("wrong input")
```

you are comparing int object with string, try **if ket==1:**

Answer (score 0):

You've already cast the first input to int, at here:

```
ket = int(input("no of kts"))
```

Since it's integer, the correct comparison should be

```
if (ket == 1):
  ...
elif (ket == 2):
  ...
```